# React redirect on page load with localstorage

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've been searching around and though I have found different methods for other kinds of redirect, I haven't found one that helps me with this one.

The idea is that I need to save a sessionID variable on localstorage, I will use this to determine if a user has logged into the application or not so that I can redirect him/her to the corresponding page. However I haven't been able to do so. Here's my code so far:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import Footer from './components/Footer/Footer';
import Home from './components/Home/Home';
import VideoGrid from './components/VideoGrid/VideoGrid'
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';


class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {sessionID: "-2", sendToGrid: false};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if(this.state.sessionID === "-1"){
        console.log("session is not started");
        console.log(this.state.sendToGrid);
    } else {
      console.log("session has started");
      this.setState( { sendToGrid: true });
      console.log(this.state.sendToGrid);
    }
  }

  render() {

    const { redirect } = this.state;

    console.log("must be sent to grid: " + redirect.sendToGrid);

    var landingPage;

    if(redirect.sendToGrid){
      landingPage = <Home />
    } else {
      landingPage = <VideoGrid />
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header />

          <Route exact={true} path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/videogrid" component={VideoGrid} />

          {landingPage}

        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Although I haven't added the localstorage variable (if someone could tell me how to do that I'd appreciate it) I'm using the burnt string as a placeholder for now. So, my idea was that once `componentDidMount()` was excecuted that I would change my state to tell the render if the session has started or not, however, the `const { redirect } = this.state;` once I write it on the console log, indicates me it's "undefinded". My idea is that if the session has started (i.e. it's set on localStorage and is not set to "-1"), the should show the VideoGrid page instead of the Home page (which has the login form).

Any help will be more than appreciated!

EDIT:

I edited my code like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import Footer from './components/Footer/Footer';
import Home from './components/Home/Home';
import VideoGrid from './components/VideoGrid/VideoGrid'
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';


class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {sessionID: "-2", sendToGrid: false};
  }



  componentWillMount() {
    if(this.state.sessionID === "-1"){
        console.log("session is not started");
        console.log(this.state.sendToGrid);
    } else {
      console.log("session has started");
      this.setState({ sendToGrid: true });
      console.log(this.state.sendToGrid);
      console.log(this.state);
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if(this.state.sessionID === "-1"){
        console.log("session is not started");
        console.log(this.state.sendToGrid);
    } else {
      console.log("session has started");
      console.log(this.state.sendToGrid);
      console.log(this.state);
    }
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header />

          <Route exact={true} path="/" render={(props) => {
            if(this.state.sessionID === "-1")
              return <Home />;
            else
              return <VideoGrid />;
          }} />
          <Route path="/videogrid" component={VideoGrid} />



        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And I'm getting the following error:

[image]

EDIT 2:

Hadn't saved the required component, hence the error shown on Edit.

Answer provided by @palsrealm solved my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `render` method of `Route` to show a component based on your logic. Something like

```
<Route exact={true} path="/" 
       render={(props)=>{
            if(this.state.sessionID ==="-1" ) return <Home/>;
            else return <VideoGrid/>;
}} />
```

The reason you are getting `undefined` when you do

```
const { redirect } = this.state;
```

is that you have not defined `redirect` in your `state` object in the constructor.

[To add a variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) to `localstorage` you need to call

```
localStorage.setItem(key,value);
```

to add the object `value` with the id `key` into your localstorage. [To access this item](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) you need to

```
let item = localStorage.getItem(key);
```

Comment: Following your answer, I changed my code into this:

 `<Route exact={true} path="/" render={(props)=>{
            if(this.state.sessionID === "-1")
              return <Home />
            else
              return <VideoGrid />
          }} />
          <Route path="/videogrid" component={VideoGrid} />`

but I'm getting this error:

"Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in"

Comment: Can you post  your edited code? or provide a codesandbox.io?

Comment: can you post the file where you define the Router? or the index.js where you  render the `App` component?

Comment: Aaahh, damn, I feel so dumb! Sorry! I hadn't hit save on my VideoGrid component, that's the reason for the most recent error. I can see that it works now, but it shows me on the same path (not /videogrid), turns out that's exactly how I needed it to work, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

To do object destructuring like

```
const {redirect} = this.state;
```

you need to have a `redirect` key in your `state` object. That is not the case. Or did you mean to just write

```
const redirect = this.state;
```